# How can I monitor a website to look for changes within a specific tag?

Tags: web-scraping

I will explain exactly what I am trying to do, and maybe someone can tell me a simple way that I can do it.

I want to track the amount of money pledged on a Kickstarter project page. The amount pledged is consistently kept within a certain tag. What are all the ways I can do this programatically?

I am just starting out to learn how to develop on the web, so that should be a good context to allow you to better help me. (I've learned bits and peices of C, Python, VB, JS, HTML/CSS)

Is there a simple hack way to do this with free tools? How would I do it all on my own? Extending this idea further, how would I notify my android device when the amount has surpassed a predefined threshold? Is this the process known as scraping? What tool do I need at my disposal to accomplish this? What language do I need to use? Do I need my own web space?

If I eventually made this concept into an android app, is there a way to only load a small portion of a website (maybe even just enough source to get to the tag I am looking for) so that I can get the data I want on the page but not have to waste a bunch of my smartphone data loading the rest of the stuff that I didn't want?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Kickstarter's API -- [do they have one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907133/does-kickstarter-have-a-public-api) -- but here is how I'd approach this problem:

1. You want to "ping" the Kickstarter periodically for information. One way to do it on Android is using [BuzzBox SDK](http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/)
2. With each execution of the background task:

   - [Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) a portion of the Kickstarter page with jQuery into your own HTML document.
   - Compare it with a threshold and possibly the previous stored value. Should be doable with basic `<=` unless you want to go anal-retentive with parsing and stuff.
   - Use [notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) in Android to notify the user once the amount is updated.
3. Wrap all this into an app.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have never even made an android app yet so this is still a little intimidating. I'm sure its simple, but I have a lot of work I'd think to get to that point, and I just don't have time now. I was able to get what I want with a google apps script: =importXml("kickstarterpageurl"; "//div/@data-pledged")